# How to Split home tabs in prestashop 1.6 ?(Popular” and “New arrivals” )

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to Split  home tabs in prestashop 1.6 ?(Popular” and “New arrivals” )
Split them into independent rows.
[image]

Can anybody help me?Ｉwould save my days. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default bootstrap theme, look at the `index.tpl` file as well as, for instance, the `blocknewproducts.php` and see how these "tabs" are implemented.

PS is using the bootstrap tabs and the modules you are talking about are hooked into `{$HOOK_HOME_TAB}` and `{$HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT}`. I would for example copy that block from `index.tpl`, create new hooks, rename the html classes and override one of the modules so it hooks into that new row. Explaining exactly how that is done goes beyond the scope of SO answers.

Comment: Thanks million. I always have a doubt. How could I located the content of the {$HOOK_HOME_TAB} and {$HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT} easily. I am just entry level of the structure.

Comment: each of the modules that display content in these 2 hooks have a `[modulename]_home.tpl` and a `tab.tpl` for the respective hooks. These modules on the index page use the bootstrap "tab" setup so it will take a little more than to just edit those templates to get them into separate rows, good luck